# Meaning of "What else is new"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I sent an email to my colleague for any questions he had, he could feel free to ask me.

This is the reply from him:

> Will do, just got sidetracked for a bit here… what else is new. =)

Should I understand "What else is new" as a question or something else? It happens to seem an informal way of saying something but I couldn't really understand the informal meaning. I know what it says literally though.

[TheFreeDictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what+else+is+new) defines it:

> Inf. This isn't new. It has happened before; Not this again.

But personally, I couldn't fit its definition in my colleague's sentence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an ironic idiom meaning that something happens frequently.  In this sentence, it means that he is always getting sidetracked.